# Animate `UITableView` headers when animating `tableHeaderView` in

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-animation

For an answer for "[How to resize a tableHeaderView of a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/how-to-resize-a-tableheaderview-of-a-uitableview/15416193#15416193)" I created a small project on [github](https://github.com/besi/ios-quickies/#resizetableheaderviewanimated), which adds a header view to a `UITableView` and animates both the newly added header view and the cells underneath it.

However, as soon as I add header cells I get a nasty UI glitch because the headers don't animate along with the cells of the `UITableView`:

When I add the header the following steps happen:

1. **Problem**: The topmost header jumps to the original position
2. The `tableHeaderView` and the `UITableViewCell`s animate together to their final position.

So my question is, how I can make sure that the headers also animate.

You can see the effect here, where the `Section-1` is at the final position, while the cells and the header view are still animating:

[image: header glitch]

This is the method, where I do the animation:

```
- (void) showHeader:(BOOL)show animated:(BOOL)animated{

    CGRect closedFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    CGRect newFrame = show?self.initialFrame:closedFrame;

    if(animated){
        // The UIView animation block handles the animation of our header view
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        // beginUpdates and endUpdates trigger the animation of our cells
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }

    self.headerView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];

    if(animated){
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the tableview style to grouped and verify. It may solve the issue.

Comment: @Dee This does not solve the issue for me, since I need the floating table view headers

Comment: Found this question, by implementing your animating header and then running into the exact same issue. I'm looking to fix as well, but dont have too much of an idea.

Comment: I meant Reproduceable, any way to edit bounty message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this will fix it, but I'm not sure if you need the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` in another part of this class. Because your `dataSource` don't really change in this example.

```
- (void)showHeader:(BOOL)show animated:(BOOL)animated {

    CGRect closedFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    CGRect newFrame = show?self.initialFrame:closedFrame;

    if(animated){
        // The UIView animation block handles the animation of our header view
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        // beginUpdates and endUpdates trigger the animation of our cells
        //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }

    self.headerView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];

    if(animated){
        //[self.tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed fix the issue for adding a tableview.tableheader, but when you remove the tableview header the original issue persists.

Comment: Ok I verified on original project and this does indeed fix the issue entirely. I'm now looking into why my implemented solution only works while showing the header and not while hiding.

Comment: if you're doing more stuff like updating/adding cells you can try to move the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` out of this `viewAnimation`. Either entirely without animation or a different animation block. Maybe this helps ;)

Comment: Weird. I'm not doing anything else that I can see. Only difference I see between the tableviews is that mine has a custom section header view. That and, the projects tableview is a static tableview and mine's a dynamic one.

Comment: Got it fixed! Looked through and there WAS in fact some unrelated code affecting the issue. I'm considering this issue as solved. Thanks. Can't give bounty for 22 hours.

Comment: This does not work for me.... It animates the table view but the header just appears over on top. I am using layout constraints on my custom table header view, if that might affect anything.