# Shrink section header of tableview, while scroll the tableview end current section, start another section header at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iphone app in which I have a `UITableViewController` in which the `tableView` contains **two sections**.

The **first section** contains a single row of height **0**.
The **second section** contains 100 rows each with a height of **44.0f**.

I am using section 0 as the title view for the `tableView`.
While the user scrolls up, section-0 header goes up and section-1 header becomes the title view for the `tableView`.
Now, instead of the Section-0 header going up, i want it to shrink while the user scrolls up.

Comment: so basically... you want section 0 header to be always visible, correct?

Comment: @staticVoidMan:No, while the tableview scroolUp, section 0 header replaced by section 1 header. In that time the section 0 header goes up you know. But in my case instead of goes up, shrink the section 0 header while section 0 replace by section 1 header

Comment: ?? what EXACTLY u want?? what it means - shrink the section 0 header while section 0 replace by section 1 header???

Comment: @user2922837: so... you want section-0 header to shrink while going up before being replaced by section-1's header... ??

Comment: @NSS:Like instagram app

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` or `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` delegate method to track the `contentOffset` of the `tableView`.
Then, logically, set the height of the section header accordingly.
i.e. To give it a shrink effect, you can slowly reduce the height of the section header until it gets replaced by the next section header.

---

Or see this: [How to resize a tableHeaderView of a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/how-to-resize-a-tableheaderview-of-a-uitableview)