# how to change height of uiview in tableview header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, cgrect

I have tableview, with a view as a child as the tableview header.

I would like the view to grow in height based on interaction with a button on the navigation bar.

I have tried to do this with the following without success:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    _submitView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _submitView.frame.size.width, 568);

    [submitView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.tableview reloadData];


}
```

Neither of the reload methods refresh the submitView so that it grows larger when the button is pressed.

How can I change the height of the view when a user triggers this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is referring to a table view header and NOT a section header then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/how-to-resize-a-tableheaderview-of-a-uitableview) question suggests that you need to set the header again after changing the frame of it - Something like this should work:

```
CGRect newFrame = headerView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height + webView.frame.size.height;
headerView.frame = newFrame;
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
```

If this is referring to a section header then sage444 has the correct method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

my be return proper height in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate method