# How to resize subviews in table to fit?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift3, frame

I have an `UITableView` which contains an `UIView` subview and the cells.

My problem is when I want to change the height frame of the subview in table, the cells are not displayed from the end of it(`UIView`) after resize. The cell will be shown from the storyboard position.

Here's how I change the frame:

```
var rct =  infoView.frame
rct.size.height = cantainerView.frame.minY + viewStatus.frame.maxY + 16
infoView.frame = rct
infoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

That are two pictures to understand my problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first view is not a cell! And I don't use AutoLayout.

Comment: do this `self.tableView.headerView = infoView;` after changing the frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize a tableHeaderView of a UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/how-to-resize-a-tableheaderview-of-a-uitableview)

Comment: Is not, because my subview is not a headerView.  The red background is the header of first section.