# access tableView header added using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView in which I have a header view that I added using drag and drop.
I want to hide it in device portrait mode and show it in landscape mode. I applied the orientation condition in the heighForHeaderInSection method and returned height 0 when in portrait mode and 70 when in landscape but it did not work as expected and added a new header space in my tableView.

How can I access the header I created in the storyboard?

Comment: Share your relevant code so we can get an idea regarding it.

Comment: Have a look at it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan that's exactly how I added my headerView but I cannot find anything in this post that describes how to resize it or access it.

Comment: @ArshBhullar Here you go 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/how-to-resize-a-tableheaderview-of-a-uitableview

Comment: Try adjusting height in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan you want me to call heightForHeaderInSection method or do tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0 ??

Comment: @ArshBhullar Have you tried my below added solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your View object is acting like `TableView` header but still you can control it with `IBOutlet` connection. Add an `IBOutlet` in your `UIViewController` like following

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableHeader: UIView!
```

and add following orientation method to hide/unhide the view with frame change.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
      if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        self.tableHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableHeader.frame.width, height: 0)
      } else {
        self.tableHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableHeader.frame.width, height: 40)
      }
  }
```